# Execute a select from two tables with same columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with same columns, I need to make a select in this two tables, I want to know how is the best way to make this, my select test is:

```
SELECT       
    ISNULL(LoteDet.IdLoteDet, LoteDetPg.IdLoteDet) AS Expr1, 
    ISNULL(LoteDet.IDSac, LoteDetPg.IDSac) AS Expr2, 
    ISNULL(LoteDet.Comprom, LoteDetPg.Comprom) AS Expr3, 
    ISNULL(LoteDet.NossoNum, LoteDetPg.NossoNum) AS Expr4,
    ISNULL(LoteDet.NossoNumDig, LoteDetPg.NossoNumDig) AS Expr5
FROM  
    LoteDet 
CROSS JOIN 
    LoteDetPg
WHERE 
    Expr1 = 500
```

It's possible to make this ?

How is the better way to execute this kind of select, if not found the value in one table, the value will be in the other table....

------ EDIT

Perhaps create a view is a good alternative to this type of select?

Comment: Are you sure you need Cartesian product?

Comment: Could you show the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Use COALESCE:

```
 SELECT       
    COALESCE(LoteDet.IdLoteDet, LoteDetPg.IdLoteDet) AS Expr1, 
    COALESCE(LoteDet.IDSac, LoteDetPg.IDSac) AS Expr2, 
    COALESCE(LoteDet.Comprom, LoteDetPg.Comprom) AS Expr3, 
    COALESCE(LoteDet.NossoNum, LoteDetPg.NossoNum) AS Expr4,
    COALESCE(LoteDet.NossoNumDig, LoteDetPg.NossoNumDig) AS Expr5
FROM  
    LoteDet 
CROSS JOIN 
    LoteDetPg
WHERE 
    Expr1 = 500
```

Take a look on this documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190349.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is going to return you what's called a Cartesian Product.  It's the result of an open join, like you have above.  That query is going to return TONS of records because you're not specifying how to JOIN the two tables, it's just going to blindly try matching columns.  At the very least, add an ON condition to the JOIN so that you can match on IDs/keys.  I think what you want is an INNER JOIN with an ON; this will return you all of the matching rows, based on ID/Key.

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN tbl1.Comprom IS NULL THEN tbl2.Comprom ELSE tbl1.Comprom END AS Expr1
   CASE WHEN tbl1.Nossonum IS NULL THEN tbl2.Nossonum ELSE tbl1.Nossonum END AS Expr2
FROM
    tbl1 --LoteDet
    INNER JOIN tbl2 --LoteDetPg
        ON (tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID)
WHERE
    Expr1 = 500 --I know I swapped the expression values, use whichever expression you need here
```

Now, only rows that have a matching ID will return you values and it will use the value from tbl1, unless it is null, then it will use the value from tbl2.

**Edit:** I know CROSS JOIN turns into an INNER JOIN if a WHERE is specified, but does the WHERE need to include both tables?  I feel that the Expr1 = 500 will still produce a Cartesian Product; can someone correct me?